# Number of Minimum Stacks required to implement Queue

Tags: queue, stack

What is the minimum number of stacks needed to implement a queue?
A queue can be implemented using 2 stacks but, Can it be implemented by using a single stack?
All the `enqueue` operations can be `push` operations to the stack and all the `dequeue` operations would be `reverse` the stack, `pop` and `reverse` it again using recursion?

Comment: Reversing a stack is cheating. It is not a standard operation on a pure stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write a recursive method to reverse a stack, so it is possible to implement a queue using a single stack. It would be horribly inefficient, but it would work. See [How to Reverse a Stack using Recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-stack-using-recursion/) for an example. Whether that counts as using only one stack is an open question. You're using only one *explicit* stack, but you're leaning pretty heavily on the process stack.

Note, however, that the size of queue you can implement this way is limited by the size of the process stack. That's usually about a megabyte. In a 64-bit process you'll be lucky to support a queue of more than about 64K items because every recursive call will push a return address and a parameter (16 bytes total). You could of course increase the process' stack size at build time.